# Comparing two columns in different tables based on condition

Tags: php, mysql

I have two tables as shown

Table1:

```
| ldt    | swpn   | nomenclature | planned | combined     |
```

Table2:

```
| lmt | name | combination |
```

I have to achieve:

1. Check if the value in column "combination" exists in the column "combined".
2. If it exists printout the corresponding `| lmt | name | combination |`

Comment: what's the question??

Comment: I edited the question now. Sorry about that!

Comment: `select * from table2 where combination in (select combined from table1)`

Answer (score 0):

Use an INNER JOIN, its used to get results from both tables on the LEFT and RIGHT of the JOIN

```
SELECT t2.lmt, t2.name, t2.combination
FROM
    t1
    INNER JOIN t2 ON t1.combined=t2.combination
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT Table2.lmt, Table2.name, Table2.combination FROM Table1, Table2 WHERE Table2.combination=Table1.combined
```

Comment: Please edit with more information. Code-only and "try this" answers are [discouraged](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/196187/is-try-this-bad-practice), because they contain no searchable content, and don't explain why someone should "try this". We make an effort here to be a resource for knowledge.